# From Quality center, Need to send automatic mail after completion of Automation run of all testcases in Test lab with attachments

Tags: email, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am using ALM / Quality center 12.53
Need to automatically send mail after the completion of automatic run of those test cases.

QC already has feature to support automatic mail trigger providing the status of each test case. What i need is to send the mail along with attachment of all test runs which has been completed recently

Any help is very appreciated. I desperately need this. couldn't achieve after trying for days

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using workflow to set that custom automail rule?. Below a sample of what I did last time in defects module, you can change that to what ever you want. I did this for version 11, newer perhaps changed, have a look at the ota guide in your alm server, that will help you build your custom code.

```
Set tdc = CreateObject("TDAPIOLE80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx "http://localhost:8080/qcbin/"
tdc.ConnectProjectEx "domain","project","user","pass"

set oFactory = tdc.BugFactory
set oFilter = oFactory.Filter
oFilter("BG_STATUS") = "'Pending User' or 'User Testing in Progress'"

SET oList = oFactory.NewList(oFilter.Text)

For Each oBug in OList
  if oBug("BG_DETECTED_BY") <> "" then
     oBug.mail oBug("BG_DETECTED_BY"), "", 0, oBug("BG_SUMMARY"), "please complete this test etc. etc."
  end if
next


tdc.logout
tdc.Disconnect
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i dont have previleges to create workflows. So have created an excel macro that downloads the latest status of tcs along with actual result for each steps in excel. & created an automatic mail trigger rule in outlook that runs the macro & send the excel as attachment to all participant whenever it receieves a mail from QC